# Running external application under Panel

Tags: vb.net

i need to write a code to run notepad inside a panel element, i've written it inside the main form but I couldn't find a solution to write it inside a panel, here is my code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer


End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Process1.StartInfo.FileName = ("notepad.exe")
    Process1.Start()

    Do Until Process1.WaitForInputIdle = True
        'Nothing
    Loop
    SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, Me.Handle)
End Sub
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `Me.Handle` with `Panel1.Handle` (or whatever your panel's name is):

```
SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
```

The second parameter of `SetParent` specifies the window handle (hWnd) of the window (= control) that you want the external process to be a child of.

In WinForms all controls that inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` expose their window handles via their [**`Handle` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: what if i want to run .bat files inside the panel ? i don't think it would work right ?

Comment: @ActosKhan : Yes it would. `.bat` files are executed in CMD, which is a process like any other. And even if launching the file directly doesn't work, you can still do it by opening the CMD process first and then instructing it to run the `.bat`.